# How to read file line by line after passing name through $_GET request in php

Tags: php

I'd like to pass a filename through a GET request to a php script.  I would have thought the following code:

```
<?php

$myFile = $_GET['filename'];

$file = fopen($myFile, "r");

while (!feof($myFile))
{
   $currentLine = fgets($myFile);
   print $currentLine;
}

?>
```

would work, but it is not.  I'm getting the following message repeated an infinite amount of times:

```
Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/getFile.php on line 7

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/getFile.php on line 9
```

I know I should be wrapping my open and while loop around an IF statement to prevent the possible opening of files that do not exist, but the file I am sending EXISTS.  It seems like I cannot do this with a GET request?

Comment: And what is the fopen() error message? Does the file exist on the server? Why are you not using the file() function for reading it line-wise. Is this actually meant to be a file upload? More context.

Comment: @mario `file()` function reads the entire file into an array, and would actually consume much more memory than advancing the file pointer line by line and outputting it, especially on large files. In this case there is no need to put the entire file in an array in memory.

Comment: @MikeBrant One could always use `SplFileObject` then if memory consumption became an issue; also allows to read line-wise.

Comment: @mario `SPLFileObject` is an excellent class for doing almost anything one could want with a file (get file metadata, find individual lines in files, place read/write locks on the file, etc.) and would certainly work here.  You should feel free to add usage example here as an alternate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$file` as the parameter for `feof()` and `fgets()`.  `$file` represents your file handle resource. `$myFile` is just a string with your file name.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while (!feof($file ))
{
   $currentLine = fgets($file );
   print $currentLine;
}
```